# Notification System with real time minutes compare

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do a notification system that will popup every exact defined minute.
I'm using Tulpep.NotificationWindow from Nuggets but i have a problem with it, it won`t pop up the notification, but works as a messagebox instead of Tulpep.NotificationWindow.

My code:

```
namespace SpawnBosi
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Thread t1;



    int channel1 = 46;
    int result;

    public Form1()

    {
        InitializeComponent();
        t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(checkforminutes));
        t1.Start();     
    }


    public void checkforminutes()
    {
        while (true)

        {
            result = DateTime.Now.Minute;
            compareminutes();
        }

    }


    public void Ch1Notificaton()
    {
        var popupNotifier = new PopupNotifier();
        popupNotifier.TitleText = "Title of popup";
        popupNotifier.ContentText = "Content text";
        popupNotifier.IsRightToLeft = false;
        popupNotifier.Popup();
    }
    public void compareminutes()
    {
        if (result == channel1)
        {
            Ch1Notificaton();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Thread t1  will check every second if the minute changed and will compare the channel1  with actual DateTime.Now.Minute.

if the time is == with channel1 set time should notify . But it donesn't work with this system. How can i resolve my problem?

UPDATE

```
    int channel1 = 25;
    int channel2 = 26;




    public Form1()

    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public void checkandcompareminutes()
    {

        int actualminute = DateTime.Now.Minute;
        if (actualminute == channel1 || actualminute == channel2)
        {
            Ch1Notificaton();         

        }

    }


    public void Ch1Notificaton()
    {
        var popupNotifier = new PopupNotifier();
        popupNotifier.TitleText = "Title of popup";
        popupNotifier.ContentText = "Content text";
        popupNotifier.IsRightToLeft = false;
        popupNotifier.Popup();



    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkandcompareminutes();
    }
}
```

Comment: you should use a `Timer` instead.

Comment: @DanielA.White should i use a timer as a what? instead of while(true)? or?

Comment: theres several timer classes that use the os instead of a loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things I would change here:

You do not need to use the object variable result. Use a local variable and combine the code of checkforminutes and compareminutes to one method.

You should use a Thread.Sleep to wait at least e.g. 500 milliseconds in your while-loop. This loop is quite exhaustive in regards to CPU time.

Overall you should better use the Timer class instead of checking the time in a while-loop.

Comment: Any ideea how can i stop the popup show everysecond>? cause i used

Comment: To stop the popup beeing shown every second you need to stop the while loop if the popup is beeing shown once.

Comment: i`ve removeed the while loop, i just use a timer set at 1000 ticks.

Comment: Then, you need to stop the timer.

Comment: if i stop the timer, it will not check anymore. Should i use two timers?